# AppDomain.AppendPrivatePath alternative?

Tags: c#, assemblies, appdomain

I read a LOT of things mostly via google (not here on SO) and didn't find something that answer to my question so I'm asking it here.

What I do want to add to "something" (to an `AppDomain` I think) so that my code can resolve AT RUNTIME how to `Assembly.CreateInstance` a specific DLL that is outside of my application's compilation folder.

I really feel like `AppDomain` is the class to use and `AppendPrivatePath` sounded like the method to use but it now is "Obsolete"...
msdn suggest to use PrivateBinPath but as far as I understood I have to create a new AppDomain and with my tests, I feel like `Assembly.CreateInstance` doesn't look for references in my new AppDomain

Some code like :

```
AppDomainSetup domaininfo = new AppDomainSetup();
domaininfo.ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
domaininfo.PrivateBinPath = "D:\\.....\\bin\\Debug\\";

Evidence adevidence = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence;

AppDomain newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("FrameworkDomain", adevidence, domaininfo);
```

works, but then, when I try to `CreateInstance`, I got a TargetInvocation exception

I, too, tried :

```
Thread.GetDomain().SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath = "D:\\.....\\bin\\Debug\\";
```

which sounds "special" but good to me, but it doesn't work...

I really feel like I HAVE TO give to `D:\\.....\\bin\\Debug\\` path to the current AppDomain but its no longer possible since `AppendPrivatePath` is Obsolete...

Any help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can resolve additional DLLs yourself on an event the assembly fires to let you know that it cannot find a type.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve += MyResolve;
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += MyResolve;

private Assembly MyResolve(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs e) {
    Console.Error.WriteLine("Resolving assembly {0}", e.Name);
    // Load the assembly from your private path, and return the result
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I might be totally of the track what you are actually trying to build but assuming that you want to build a plugin infrastructure where you want to organize plugins in subfolders like this:

```
\plugins\foo\foo.dll
\plugins\foo\dependency_that_foo_needs.dll
\plugins\bar\bar.dll
\plugins\bar\dependency_that_bar_needs.dll
```

The problem that you encountered is that that foo.dll fails to load its dependency because the framework does not look in that subdirectory for the assembly to load.

Using the latest preview of the Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF 2 Preview) one can build such things really easy. I assume you could even do that with an earlier version, however earlier versions forced you to use special attributes on your plugins that the most recent version does not depend on any longer.

So, assume that is your plugin contract:

```
public interface IPlugin
{
    string Run();
}
```

To load and run all plugins in \plugins\foo\, \plugins\bar\, (...) just use this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var registration = new RegistrationBuilder();
        registration.ForTypesDerivedFrom<IPlugin>().Export().Export<IPlugin>();

        var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo("./plugins");

        var directoryCatalogs = directoryInfo
            .GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Select(dir => new DirectoryCatalog(dir.FullName, registration));

        var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(directoryCatalogs);

        var container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);
        container
            .GetExportedValues<IPlugin>()
            .ForEach(plugin => Console.WriteLine(plugin.Run()));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

As I said, I might be totally of the track but chances are also that someone looking for an alternative finds it useful :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about using

```
Assembly.LoadFrom("..path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an EventHandler to the Appdomains `AssemblyResolve` event and then load your assemblies form your special private path.